# Unwanted small space on left and right side of images

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place three images horizontally side by side inside a container div. I have tried two methods first using the container div as a table and second method using a flex box. The codesandbox link is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-dream-bbnvb9).

First method html/css is given below:

```css
.multiple-images-parent {
  display: table;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 0;
}

.multiple-images4 {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 2px solid black;
  line-height: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.multiple-images4 img {
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: calc(100% / 3 - 40px / 3);
}

.multiple-images4 img:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="multiple-images-transform">
  <div class="multiple-images-transform2">
    <img src="test1.jpg">
    <img src="test1.jpg">
    <img src="test1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Second Method html/css is:

```css
.multiple-images-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.multiple-images-flex img {
  margin-right: 20px;
  max-width: calc(100% / 3 - 40px / 3);
}

.multiple-images-flex img:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="multiple-images-flex">
  <img src="test1.jpg">
  <img src="test1.jpg">
  <img src="test1.jpg">
</div>
```

The images align correctly.
However incase of table container a tiny space shows between the right image and the right border of the container div.
In case of flexbox container a tiny space shows between the right image and the right border of the container div and also between the left image and left border of the container

Can you please help understand why this space is showing up?

Comment: You should put the CSS and HTML in the same snippet so it illustrates the behavior.  When you put CSS in one snippet and corresponding HTML in another, it defeats the point of using a snippet

Comment: It may be browser related. I can see it on chrome but on firefox the gaps are not present.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `justify-content: space-between`? I can't seem to reproduce your problem. For a more predictable behavior I set the `img` to be `display: inline-block` or `block` will also work.

```css
.multiple-images-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.multiple-images-flex img {
  margin-right: 20px;
  max-width: calc(100% / 3 - 40px / 3);
  display: inline-block;
}

.multiple-images-flex img:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="multiple-images-flex">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/150">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/150">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I tried space-between. It did not help. By the way in your solution I see a tiny gap between left image and left border of container. Right side is ok.